# Derive the module name of each node from computational graph in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

By using `torch.fx.symbolic_trace({pt_model}).graph` method, I successfully get the nodes information consisting of the model. When analyzing the node information, the operator's name is written in like `placeholder`, `call_module` not the name of modules such as `Conv1`, `BatchNorm`.

I'd want to get the name of modules from the result of the symbolic_trace method.
How can I do this?

The below picture is an example of what I do symbolic_trace on the ResNet-50 model.

[image]